# Adding horizontal line under chapter number but before chapter title, without adding the line to the table of contents

Tags: formatting, chapters, titlesec

I'm trying to format my report chapter titles to have a horizontal line under the chapter number but above the name of the chapter such that it reads

Chapter
'horizontal line'
Name of Chapter

I can do this using `\titlesec` straightforwardly enough, however it also adds the horizontal line to the table of contents, list of figures, etc. that I don't want. Is there an easy way to remedy this? I've tried various positions of the horizontal line in the `\titleformat` command but to no avail. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\Large\scshape}
{\chaptername~\thechapter}
{-12pt}
{\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.8pt}\\\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    
    
    \tableofcontents % I don't want the horizontal line above this
    
    \chapter{Example Title}
    
    Here is the text in the chapter.
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simply move the `\titleformat` macro invocation *after* the `\tableofcontents`. (It need not be in the preamble)

Comment: Such an easy fix, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you wanna table of content heading still centered as well. There is a way to use the `\titleformat` still in the preamble, and not influence the star version of the `\chapter` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\Large\scshape}
{\chaptername~\thechapter\\[-10pt]\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.8pt}}
{-2pt}
{\Huge\bfseries}

\begin{document}
    
\tableofcontents
    
\chapter{Example Title 1}
    Here is the text in the chapter.

\chapter*{Example Title 2}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I was planning on redefining the commands to centre the table of contents etc. but this solution removes that need - very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As commented, merely move the invocation of the`\titleformat` command *after* the `\tableofcontents`.  That way, the format will not be changed until after the Table of Contents is typeset.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\begin{document}
    
    
    \tableofcontents % I don't want the horizontal line above this
    
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\centering\Large\scshape}
{\chaptername~\thechapter}
{-12pt}
{\rule{0.5\linewidth}{0.8pt}\\\Huge\bfseries}

    \chapter{Example Title}
    
    Here is the text in the chapter.
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]